# query an XML file using PHP

Tags: php, xml

Using PHP5 is there a way to query an XML file similar to querying a database? If I had an XML file with 50 hotel entries, how could I query the XML file to get a specific entry? Also could I reorganize the XML entries by field such as a date field? So if I wanted to display the entries in descending date order could I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible by using xpath ([simplexml](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) or [domxpath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php))

However to sort is unintuitive

example using simplexml :

```
$str = '<hotels>
  <hotel>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Hilton</name>
    <date>2011-01-01</date>
  </hotel>
  <hotel>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>Accor</name>
    <date>2011-01-02</date>
  </hotel>
  <hotel>
    <id>3</id>
    <name>Sands</name>
    <date>2011-01-03</date>
  </hotel>
  ... etc
</hotels>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);

/* find a specic hotel with name=Sands */
$found = $xml->xpath('/hotels/hotel/name[.="Sands"]');

/* order by date */
$sort = array();
foreach ($xml->hotel as $obj)
{
  $sort[(string)$obj->date] = $obj;
}
arsort($sort);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Meaning if I had a xml file with 50 hotel entries, using PHP5 could I query the xml file to get a specific entry?

Take a look at [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp).

**Edit:** Ok I shouldn't read so fast, take a look at [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php), this will allow you to load the XML file and perform queries on it, more specifically, look at [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php).